# Too few arguments to function Pembelian::tambah_pembelian_proses(),

Tags: php, codeigniter

I try to code this in `Codeigniter` HMVC

controller :

```
public function tambah_pembelian_proses($id) {
    //menambahkan ke tabel pembelian
    $data = array(
        'tgl_beli' => $this->input->post('tgl_beli'),
        'waktu' => $this->input->post('waktu'),
        'nomor_po' => $this->input->post('nomor_po'),
        'nomor_manual' => $this->input->post('nomor_manual'),
        'id_koderek' => $this->input->post('id_koderek'),
        'id_supplier' => $this->input->post('id_supplier'),
        'subtotal' => $this->input->post('subtotal'),
        'username' => $this->input->post('username')
    );
    $update = $this->db->update('pembelian',$data,array('nomor_po' => $id));
    //end menambahkan ke tabel pembelian

    //menambahkan ke tabel pembelian_sementara
    $data4 = array(
        'tgl_beli' => $this->input->post('tgl_beli'),
        'waktu' => $this->input->post('waktu'),
        'nomor_po' => $this->input->post('nomor_po'),
        'nomor_manual' => $this->input->post('nomor_manual'),
        'id_koderek' => $this->input->post('id_koderek'),
        'id_supplier' => $this->input->post('id_supplier'),
        'nama_user' => $this->input->post('nama_user'),
        'subtotal' => $this->input->post('subtotal')
    );
    $insert = $this->db->insert('pembelian_sementara',$data4);
    //end menambahkan ke tabel pembelian_sementara

    //menambahkan ke tabel pembelian_detail
    $nomor_po_beli = $_POST['nomor_po_beli'];
    $kode_brg = $_POST['kode_brg'];
    $nama_barang = $_POST['nama_barang'];
    $satuan = $_POST['satuan'];
    $hrg = $_POST['hrg'];
    $beli_qty = $_POST['beli_qty'];
    $beli_total = $_POST['beli_total'];
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $data2 = array();

    $index = 0;
    foreach ($nomor_po_beli as $data_nomor_po_beli){
        array_push($data2, array(
            'nomor_po_beli' => $data_nomor_po_beli,
            'kode_brg' => $kode_brg[$index],
            'nama_barang' => $nama_barang[$index],
            'satuan' => $satuan[$index],
            'hrg' => $hrg[$index],
            'beli_qty' => $beli_qty[$index],
            'beli_total' => $beli_total[$index],
            'user' => $user[$index]
        ));

        //tambah stok
        //$this->db->query("update barang set stock=stock+'$beli_qty[$index]' where kode_brg='$kode_brg[$index]'"); //Tambah Add Stock
        $index++;

    }

    $insert_detail = $this->m_pembelian->simpan_pembelian_detail($data2);
    //end menambahkan ke tabel pembelian_detail

    //menambahkan ke tabel add_to_terima
    $nomor_po_beli = $_POST['nomor_po_beli'];
    $kode_brg = $_POST['kode_brg'];
    $nama_barang = $_POST['nama_barang'];
    $satuan = $_POST['satuan'];
    $hrg = $_POST['hrg'];
    $beli_qty = $_POST['beli_qty'];
    $beli_total = $_POST['beli_total'];
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $data3 = array();

    $index = 0;
    foreach ($nomor_po_beli as $data_nomor_po_beli){
        array_push($data3, array(
            'nomor_po_beli' => $data_nomor_po_beli,
            'kode_brg' => $kode_brg[$index],
            'nama_barang' => $nama_barang[$index],
            'satuan' => $satuan[$index],
            'hrg' => $hrg[$index],
            'beli_qty' => $beli_qty[$index],
            'beli_total' => $beli_total[$index],
            'user' => $user[$index]
        ));

        //tambah stok
        //$this->db->query("update barang set stock=stock+'$beli_qty[$index]' where kode_brg='$kode_brg[$index]'"); //Tambah Add Stock
        $index++;

    }
    $insert_terima = $this->m_pembelian->simpan_add_to_terima($data3);
    //$insert_terima = $this->db->insert('add_to_terima',$data3,array('id_add_terima' => $id));
    //end menambahkan ke tabel add_to_terima

    if ($insert_detail){
        $username_cart = $this->session->userdata("username");
        $delete = $this->db->delete('add_to_cart',array('username_cart' => $username_cart));
    } else {
        redirect('pembelian/lihat_pembelian/'.$id);
    }

    redirect('pembelian/lihat_pembelian/'.$id);
}
```

and the result is

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: ArgumentCountError
>
> Message: Too few arguments to function Pembelian::tambah_pembelian_proses(), 0 passed in C:\xampp7.3.2\htdocs\egupers\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 532 and exactly 1 expected
>
> Filename: C:\xampp7.3.2\htdocs\egupers\application\modules\pembelian\controllers\Pembelian.php
>
> Line Number: 64
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp7.3.2\htdocs\egupers\index.php
> Line: 315
> Function: require_once

Comment: tambah_pembelian_proses($id='') try this, Can you tell me from where you are to call this function tambah_pembelian_proses()

Comment: hello, from this : 
public function tambahnopoproses(){
        $data = array(
            'nopopem' => $this->input->post('nopopem'),
        );
        $insert = $this->db->insert('nomor_po_pembelian',$data);

        $data1 = array(
            'nomor_po' => $this->input->post('nopopem'),
        );
        $insert = $this->db->insert('pembelian',$data1);

        $nopopem = $this->input->post('nopopem');
        redirect('pembelian/tambah_pembelian/'.$nopopem);
    }

Comment: did you try my above line change?

Comment: yeah, it's work, there are some of script i've change, thanks Mr. M.Hemmant